# How to copty only the value and not the formula into another workbook ? (openpyxl)

Tags: openpyxl

I will not put all my script, for the sake of clarity.

I created a workbook, where I stored data based on an csv files, then I created cells who contains sums of those data :

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

sheet = wb.active
sheet2=wb.create_sheet('somme')

sheet['C16'] = '= SUM(A100:A212)'
sheet['D16'] = '= SUM(B100:B212)'
sheet['E16'] = '= SUM(C100:C212)'
sheet['F16'] = '= SUM(D100:D212)'
```

But I want the sums to be in another sheet, but not the formula, just the value, because otherwise it will be 0 because in `sheet2` there is no data to sum.

I tried this :

```
for row in sheet['A1':'Z100']:
    for cell in row:
        sheet2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value
```

But it return formula, so I don't have the number, just 0.

Any ideas how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by having the cells in `sheet2` reference the sum cells with a formula, like `=Sheet1!C16`.

If you already know the title of `sheet`, you can just use that directly. If not, it's probably a good idea to use `openpyxl.utils.cell.quote_sheetname()` to avoid potential issues with spaces:

```python
sheet2[cell.coordinate].value = f"={quote_sheetname(sheet.title)}!{cell.coordinate}"
```

Another approach, if you don't want the sums in the main worksheet, would be to put the sum formulas directly in `sheet2`, and add the title of the first worksheet to the cell ranges.